# cart not getting empty after success page redirection done in magento 2

Tags: magento2, mini-cart, success-message, empty

> How can I empty my cart value when order successfully done in Magento
> 2. This issue only done with logged-in user how can I handle this issue. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: This issue you faced in minicart right?

Comment: Yes I'm facing this issue on minicart but when I reload success page its  redirect to cart page also which  is not empty

Comment: you have installed any extension that customizes the cart? Or check the order that you have placed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For update minicart section first we create a sections.xml in /etc/frontend/

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="test/process/observer">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
</config>
```

And after apply Ajax on particular section phtml

And one more solution founded

```
require([
           'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
        ], function (customerData) {
            var sections = ['cart'];
            customerData.invalidate(sections);
            customerData.reload(sections, true);
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response